# Pass Values from ASPX Page to User Control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a value in Page Load. I want to pass that value to User control.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    UserEmail = UserSession.EmployeeEmail
End Sub
```

How Can I pass this UserEmail to User control ?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post, the code for the user control being declared, as well as some info about `UserSession`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `UserEmail` is a custom user control and assuming that `UserSession.EmployeeEmail` is a `string` you could do the following:

In the definition for your custom control, you add a public property

```
' user control code behinde
Public Property  EmailAddress As String
```

Then in the page that is hosting the user control

```
' page load of host aspx
UserEmail.EmailAddress = UserSession.EmployeeEmail
```

In my example here I used `String` but as long as the type matches between your user control property and the `UserSession.EmployeeEmail`, you should be good to go.

Comment: Hello, UserEmail is Just a string not a custom user control

Comment: Then what exactly is the issue? I need to see more code, specific to the issue, to see what is going wrong.